# Converting chars to int from serial port in C

Tags: c, xbee

I am using this source code to read from the serial port of a linux machine. I am able to read from the port, but all of the values are in ascii gibberish ( i am reading the input from an xbox controller). I know I am sending it correctly, i.e. i can see on my side I am sending -128 - 127 as a char, but when I am converting it on my linux machine using atoi its returning 0, or when I try to cast the data to int it returns -48 , equivalent to 0 in ascii.

Is there a way for me to convert the incoming ascii into a readable integer like 64 or -114? I appreciate any help, thank you.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

#include "rs232.h"



int main()
{
  int i, n,
      cport_nr=0,        /* /dev/ttyS0 (COM1 on windows) */
      bdrate=9600;       /* 9600 baud */

  unsigned char buf[4096];

  char mode[]={'8','N','1',0};


  if(RS232_OpenComport(cport_nr, bdrate, mode))
  {
    printf("Can not open comport\n");

    return(0);
  }

  while(1)
  {
    n = RS232_PollComport(cport_nr, buf, 4095);

    if(n > 0)
    {
      buf[n] = 0;   /* always put a "null" at the end of a string! */

      for(i=0; i < n; i++)
      {
        if(buf[i] < 32)  /* replace unreadable control-codes by dots */
        {
          buf[i] = '.';
        }
      }

      printf("received %i bytes: %s\n", n, (char *)buf);
    }

#ifdef _WIN32
    Sleep(100);
#else
    usleep(100000);  /* sleep for 100 milliSeconds */
#endif
  }

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Why on earth don't you just print `n`?  `printf("%d ", n);`  You need to study the C language and learn about data types.

Comment: What do you mean? I am printing n, but that's just the number of bytes I am receiving, not the data itself.

Comment: Then print the bytes the same way: `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%d ", buf[i]);`

Comment: I cant print it the same way because I cannot convert it correctly.

If I use atoi it returns 0, if I cast it to a char it returns -48, if I use strtol, or sscanf, it returns an exceptionally large value (dont quite know what this means, but its in the billions). Sscanf and strtol dont require the char thats input to be signed or unsigned, but I am getting a warning using an unsigned char. I have to use an unsigned char, because the method I use requires it. Do you think there is a way to get around that?

Comment: You don't need to conver with `atoi`. That's for converting an _ASCII_ string to an integer. You want to convert an integer to _ASCII_. `printf` as I showed will do that.  If you want to see the value in 0..255, then use `printf("%u ", (unsigned)buf[i]);`

Comment: Why do you need to convert it if it is already ascii characters as  you claim? Your question is quite unclear. It would help if you gave the exact data that has been read. Just dump it out as raw hex or decimal to start with. And then show what conversion you tried and what the exact output was.

Comment: Thanks I think you got it! I appreciate it

Comment: one more question, when I am sending a zero value over the serial port (or any value below 32), the linux machine is reading it and interpreting the value as NULL i believe, and outputting 46, do you know why this is?